# from django.db import connection giving error in django1.4

Tags: python, django, postgresql, importerror, django-settings

I was trying to connect to the database by using the command

```
from django.db import connection
```

from the python shell
but this produced the following Import error

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    if DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS not in settings.DATABASES:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

Im using Django 1.4 and PostgreSQL
the same command was executed sucessfully when i was using the earlier versions of django
Plz help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set an OS environ value for DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.  You can do that with a simple EXPORT command.  If you are using virtualenv, I hightly recommend virtualenvwrapper and I put this setting in the 'bin/postactivate' file.

Note: I just tested it via the django 1.4 shell and the import works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your `manage.py` file defines DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE. Since your running this code outside of your django application, you need to define it yourself.

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", <location of settings.py>)
```

Comment: My manage.py file already conatins the right location on my settings.py

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was saying. When you are in a basic python shell, you never run the line in manage.py that sets DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE. Therefore it's not available to you in that instance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. The easiest way to do it is to put the following code at the top of the file that contains your failing import statement:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'path/to/your/settings.py'
# ...
from django.db import connection
```

Comment: I m trying to execute
"from django.db import connection" through python shell on the terminal, plz guide me what i have to do in this case.

Comment: Are you using the Django shell (`python manage.py shell`) from within your Django project? I think you don't. If you use the Django shell, all the necessary environment variables are set automatically, so that you don't have to care about it.

Comment: Actually im using the Django shell from my django Project.
the command ran without problem in previous django verision,it creating prob in django 1.4

Comment: That's strange, for me it works just fine with Django 1.4. But I'm using SQlite. Since your failing import statement seems to call your database, it might be an issue with PostgreSQL. If this is the case, I cannot help you (no experience with PostgreSQL).